# Setting javascript input value using Excel VBA without the Option value

Tags: javascript, ajax, vba, excel

**Situation**

I'm trying to automate a login and search for a website using VBA in Excel.  I'm able to open IE, navigate, login and get to the search page.  The website has a listbox that has the options added dynamically using AJAX.  The code looks like:

```
<select id="listArray" multiple="" name="listArray" onchange="deSelectAll();" size="13" style="width: 324px">
<option value="172743306">Bob Smith (bob.smith@gmail.com)</option>
<option value="116696948">Abby Hernandez (ahernandez@ymail.com)</option>
```

etc, etc.  There are around 100 names and being dynamic the list can change from time to time.  On the rendered webpage, the user simply clicks on the name/email address and clicks the submit button.

**The Issue**

I know how to set the `.Value` of the box if I have that option value number.  However, it is assigned by the site and meaningless to me.  I want to be able to set the option using VBA given the name and/or email address.  e.g. I want to be able to type in "Bob Smith" and have VBA search or find that name and get the option value from there.  I have searched SO and Google without luck; what I can find assumes that you have the option value or can just grab it from the page source.

**Code**

For other sites where I've had the option value, I've used:

```
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "user" Then
    objCollection(i).Value = userName
    End If
Wend
```

or similar without problems.  I'm hoping that `getElementsByTagName` has some property I could use to find the display text (the name in my situation) or there would be an easy way to search the code.  Any ideas to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: if getElementsByTagName works, then maybe so will querySelectorAll(), in which case you can do "select option[name='user']" to find the option(s).

Comment: You can loop through the options in the list: each option has a .Text and a .Value property.  When you find a matching Text property, set the value accordingly. Or set the select's selectedIndex to the option's index (zero-based)

Comment: Use `IE.document.getelementbyid("listArray")` instead of `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")` and as Tim suggested loop thru options to get the Text & Value property.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments.  Using `getElementByID` successfully returns the box, but I'm not sure how to loop through the options to check the `.Text` of each option.  Reading the [properties and methods for IHTMLElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I don't see how I would do it.  How do I access the collection of options from the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim s

Set s = IE.document.getElementById("listArray")
SetSelectByText s, "Bob Smith"



Sub SetSelectByText(sel, txt)
Dim l As Long, x As Long
    l = sel.Options.Length
    For x = 0 To l - 1
        If sel.Options(x).Text Like "*" & txt & "*" Then
            sel.selectedIndex = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```